# Daydreaming about many topics in free time

Tags: mind

I read a lot of questions and answers and discussions on this website, thanks to its active members and moderators. But I realised that now I am spending time in spiral of thoughts in my free time, and it is rightly said that anything done in excess is bad. How should one avoid overthinking and focus on whatever they are doing at the moment?

Comment: Why don't you read upnishads, brahm sutras and bhagvad gita to get answer of your spiral of thoughts. Also I think you should go to other stack exchange for asking about overthinking